Issues using snipping tool to attempt to grab items from a drop down menu
Snipping tool max delay set at 5 seconds and confirmed. Then I open (right click) my Windows 10 explorer on a desktop folder the drop down menu (many items) shows, but if I do anything to copy it the menu goes away instantly before anything is copied.
My keyboard lacks a ScrnPrnt key, I'd think that might work, but the menu clears in a flash if I try Snipping, or other shareware or purchased software screen copiers.
I want this list, because I'm trying to elicit help on capturing this excessively long menu of choices I don't need. I'd like to prune it down, that's where I'm headed.
The tool on source forge displays known as ShellNewHandler lists only about 25% of what's in that drop menu that it could even act on. It seems a lot of installed software decided for me that I need them in that list, and that tool doesn't see them all. I might have a half dozen I use because keyboard shortcuts get me most of what I use routinely.
Anyway that's the end goal but I next need to show someone what's in that list which is excessive. I have a 27" monitor and it's running at its highest DPI, so the type I'm looking at is about 10 pitch, and this drop down menu lists so many items it takes 2/3rds of the screen's height
I have vision problems that will get worse, so having that list reduced to what I use most so I can enlarge the fonts as my vision digresses will help. I think my monitor is set at 1900x1080 if memory serves, and so you can imagine how that drop down has way too many choices.

Did you try win+shift+S ?

Is that an issue only in that program, or for all of your programs and drop down or context menus? For me when I snip-screenshot, context menus briefly disappear but then appear again with the snip tool then available.

Use a powershell script to take a screenshot.  Add a sleep, like: sleep 10; screenshot "D:\screenshot.png" to give yourself 10 seconds to get the menu up.
